# Is there a notation to designate a random variable given it's distribution and vice versa?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, notation

Most of the times, I find it unnecessary and tedious to name the corresponding random variables of a given bunch of probability density functions.

For example, one must write things like this even if not interested in the variables but in the probability density functions:

*If $X_1$ ~ $f$ and $X_2$ ~ $g$, then $X_1 + X_2$ ~ $f*g$*, or

*If $X_1$ ~ $exp(\lambda)$ and $X_2$ ~ $exp(\lambda)$, then $X_1 + X_2$ ~ $erlang(2,\lambda)$*

I would like to avoid making up random names for every function involved. Is there a standard notation which can allow me to write things like the following?

$RV(f) + RV(g) = RV(f*g)$, or $PDF( RV(f) + RV(g) ) = f*g$, or $PDF^{-1}(f) = RV(f*g) - RV(g)$, or $RV(exp(\lambda)) + RV(exp(\lambda)) = RV(erlang(2,\lambda))$

where $RV$ stands for random variable of a given pdf, and PDF is the pdf of a given random variable. (Note: $PDF^{-1}=RV$, and vice versa)

Comment: May be using $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$

Comment: But you are given the functions, not the variables

Comment: The main problem is that all you have writen is only true if the random variables are independants...